# accessing json data passed from php (json_encode(databaseresults))

Tags: php, json

I am using json_encode in my php function to send the multiple results from database to an ajax call.

i am getting the result back in the following format..

```
[
    {
        "id": 24,
        "title": "Mr",
        "first_name": "Patrick",
        "last_name": "Vinc",
        "gender": "male",
        "email": "nupur@gmail.com",
        "password": "$2y$10$yCyGBOtX6kF3ghy/k8YuXe4wR9W5hYtTGDkl5trTEd7.s5LntOQ.u",
        "phone_type": null,
        "phone_number": "0000000000",
        "pager_number": "00000000000000",
        "address_line_1": "",
        "address_line_2": "",
        "city": "",
        "postal_code": "",
        "province": "BC",
        "country": null,
        "emc_contact": "",
        "emc_phone": "000000000000000000",
        "emc_relation": "",
        "passcode": "",
        "locker": "999999",
        "combination": "abc567",
        "its_username": null,
        "its_password": null,
        "dictation_number": null,
        "emailed": 1,
        "signed": 0,
        "student_num": "12345634",
        "level": "Default",
        "persist_code": "",
        "activated_at": "2014-08-23 16:04:18",
        "program": null,
        "school": "",
        "service": "",
        "undergrad_year": null,
        "undergrad_level": null,
        "activated": 1,
        "activation_code": "",
        "undergrad_text": null,
        "cpso_num": 0,
        "start_date": "2014-08-01",
        "end_date": "2014-08-31",
        "learner_start_date": "0000-00-00",
        "learner_end_date": "0000-00-00",
        "vacation_start_date": "0000-00-00",
        "vacation_end_date": "0000-00-00",
        "physician": "1",
        "affiliates": null,
        "mask": "",
        "mask_fit_month_year": "",
        "learner_type": null,
        "status": 1,
        "last_login": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
        "reset_password_code": "",
        "permissions": "",
        "created_at": "-0001-11-30 00:00:00",
        "updated_at": "2014-08-22 21:27:17"
    }
]
```

How can I access this data? I want to get the first name and the last name.

Comment: You are getting a JSON response back, therefore you should use http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps

```
$json = json_decode($jsondata);

foreach ($json as $item)
{
    echo $item->first_name;
    echo $item->last_name;
}
```

to Do the same in Javascript:

```
for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
   var item=data[i];
   console.log(item['first_name']);//Or item.first_name also works
   console.log(item['last_name']);// 
}
```

Comment: Thanks but how can I do the same in AJAX?

Comment: Are you trying to access the data using JavaScript or PHP?

Comment: I have updated in both javascript and PHP. If this solves the problem please accept the answer

Comment: Take the `true` flag out of your PHP solution. Otherwise the decode will return an associative array, not an object. Make sure your answer is correct before getting pushy.

Comment: @AnkitLadhania Not yet..I have used function newLearner() {
  var firstname = $('input[name=new_first_name]').val();
   var URL = "/teghlearner/public/admin/newLearner";
   var info ={
    "firstname":firstname,
    "lastname" : lastname,
    "student_id" : student_id
    };

    
$.ajax({
      type: "post",
      url: URL,
      data : info,
      success: function(result) {
        for(var i=0;i<result.length;i++){
   var item=data[i];
   alert(item['first_name']);
   alert(item['last_name']);
}  
      },

      
    });


}

Comment: I have answered the question that was titled , in order to ask another question please make another question in SO. so that if it helps the future readers to distinguish the problem. Please accept this answer and after making the new question send me the link.

Comment: @AnkitLadhania Please see the question in the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25466891/cant-solve-code-in-ajax-php-json-laravelphp-framework.

Answer (score -1):

I think you're trying to retrieve JSON via an AJAX request to a PHP application right?

You will need to make an AJAX request to your PHP application which should respond appropriately (with the JSON data)

I believe you need something like:

```
$.post( "ajax/test.html", function( data ) {
  for (item in data){
    console.log(item.first_name);
    console.log(item.last_name);
  }
});
```

Make sure you're actually echoing the response back from the PHP application.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: It's just an example of an AJAX post to access response data. I'll amend the answer