# Can't solve code in Ajax,PHP,Json,Laravel(PHP Framework)

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json, laravel

Can't access the json encoded data sent from a php function(Using laravel framework) to an ajax call.
I am encoding the database results
This is the php function I am using 
    public function newLearner(){

```
            $first_name = $_POST['firstname'];
            $last_name = $_POST['lastname'];
            $student_id = $_POST['student_id'];

          if(!empty($first_name) && empty($last_name) && empty($student_id)){
           $learner = Learners::where('first_name','=',$first_name)->get();

            return json_encode($learner);

          }
```

On the javascript side I have used:

```
function newLearner() {

  var firstname = $('input[name=new_first_name]').val();
  var lastname = $('input[name=new_last_name]').val();
  var student_id = $('input[name=new_id]').val();
  //alert(firstname);
   var URL = "/teghlearner/public/admin/newLearner";
   var info ={
    "firstname":firstname,
    "lastname" : lastname,
    "student_id" : student_id
    };


$.ajax({
      type: "post",
      url: URL,
      data : info,

      success: function(result) {


        //alert(result['first_name']);
        for(var i=0;i<result.length;i++){
   var item=result[i];
   alert(item['first_name']);
   alert(item['last_name']);
}




      },

       error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

        $('#data').html(result);

    }

    });


}


And this is the JSON Returned from the php function

[
    {
        "id": 24,
        "title": "Mr",
        "first_name": "Patrick",
        "last_name": "Vinc",
        "gender": "male",
        "email": "nupur@gmail.com",
        "password": "$2y$10$yCyGBOtX6kF3ghy/k8YuXe4wR9W5hYtTGDkl5trTEd7.s5LntOQ.u",
        "phone_type": null,
        "phone_number": "0000000000",
        "pager_number": "00000000000000",
        "address_line_1": "",
        "address_line_2": "",
        "city": "",
        "postal_code": "",
        "province": "BC",
        "country": null,
        "emc_contact": "",
        "emc_phone": "000000000000000000",
        "emc_relation": "",
        "passcode": "",
        "locker": "999999",
        "combination": "abc567",
        "its_username": null,
        "its_password": null,
        "dictation_number": null,
        "emailed": 1,
        "signed": 0,
        "student_num": "12345634",
        "level": "Default",
        "persist_code": "",
        "activated_at": "2014-08-23 16:04:18",
        "program": null,
        "school": "",
        "service": "",
        "undergrad_year": null,
        "undergrad_level": null,
        "activated": 1,
        "activation_code": "",
        "undergrad_text": null,
        "cpso_num": 0,
        "start_date": "2014-08-01",
        "end_date": "2014-08-31",
        "learner_start_date": "0000-00-00",
        "learner_end_date": "0000-00-00",
        "vacation_start_date": "0000-00-00",
        "vacation_end_date": "0000-00-00",
        "physician": "1",
        "affiliates": null,
        "mask": "",
        "mask_fit_month_year": "",
        "learner_type": null,
        "status": 1,
        "last_login": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
        "reset_password_code": "",
        "permissions": "",
        "created_at": "-0001-11-30 00:00:00",
        "updated_at": "2014-08-22 21:27:17"
    }
]
```

How can I get the first_name and last_name from this JSON data in the javascript function? 
Issues

Comment: Do you even get something returned from the php script? Make use of the browsers developer tools.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois Yes I am getting json data from php. I have mentioned the result I am getting as json.

Comment: If you are not sure what your actual data structure looks like, then log the object you are receiving in response to your AJAX call to the browser’s console, so that you can inspect it.

Comment: @CBroe 
This is the format of JSON i am getting as result
[
    {
        "id": 24,
        "title": "Mr",
        "first_name": "Patrick",
        "last_name": "Vinc",
        "gender": "male",
        "start_date": "2014-08-01",
        "end_date": "2014-08-31",
        "learner_start_date": "0000-00-00",
        "learner_end_date": "0000-00-00",
        "vacation_start_date": "0000-00-00",
        "vacation_end_date": "0000-00-00",
    }
]

Comment: Your JSON is invalid. The last comma after the vacation_end_date is creating an invalid JSON string. Have your tried Response::json rather than json_encode?

Comment: Simple as this `result[0]['first_name']` added `[0]` because it's an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the content-type on the response is text/html. This makes jquery think the response is html. jquery does not parse the json in that case. To solve this problem simply remove the json_encode. Your laravel controller should look like this:

```
$first_name = Input::get('firstname');
$last_name = Input::get('lastname');
$student_id = Input::get('student_id');

if(!empty($first_name) && empty($last_name) && empty($student_id)) {
    return Learners::where('first_name','=',$first_name)->get();
}
```

This works because when you return a collection, Laravel will automatically convert it to json and set the content-type to application/json.

Also note that you should use the Input facade to get the post variables rather than using the _POST superglobal.